# Does electric current prevent corrosion or oxidation?

Tags: current, ground

I often see overhead power lines without any shielding from the elements. Are these lines galvanized or does current protect them from corrosion?  Wouldn't the electron flow through the metal wires prevent oxygen from bonding to it?  At the same time, however, you could claim it would have no effect. The corrosive elements, air, water, etc, do not have the same voltage reference.

Finally, can carefully limited electric current be used as an anti-corrosion method?

Comment: Overhead power lines are usually made from aluminium (aluminum) with a steel core for strength.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current *thru* a metal has no effect on corrosion.  However, corrosion is a electro-chemical process, so current into or out of a conductor does effect its chemical activity over surface the current flows into or out of.

This is exactly the effect galvanizing exploits to reduce corrosion of ferrous metals.  The zinc coating does directly protect the metal underneath.

However, the special properties of galvanizing kick in when there is a hole in the zinc protective layer.  Now you have zinc and iron exposed to the same electrolyte.  A current will flow due to this battery.  The direction of the current is such to reduce corrosion of the iron, while instead corroding the zinc.

In some cases, like off shore oil platforms for example, it is cheaper and more effective to put zinc anodes in various places than to coat the steel with zinc.  One advantage is that the zinc electrodes can be periodically replaced as they get corroded away.  In fact they are often referred to as *sacrificial* anodes.  Divers going down and replacing the zinc blocks is part of routine maintenance.

Comment: Wow!  Are you telling me I can have a nice rust free cast iron saw tabletop by placing small pieces of zinc on top of it?

Comment: @user: No, since a few pieces of zinc scattered about isn't going to cover most of the cast iron surface.  Most of the cast iron will oxidize directly with only moisture in the air acting as a electrolyte at best.  There is no means for the open end of the zinc to make a closed circuit back to the open face of the case iron.

Comment: You sure know a hell of a lot about Electronics.  Are you a top engineer at one of those semiconductor companies?